# strictly positive compact operator do not exist?

Tags: functional-analysis

I face a problem, where I derive a contradiction which is the existence of an strictly positive operator $A \in L(H)$ in a infinit dimensional Hilbert space $H$
i.e. $\langle Ax,x\rangle\geq c\|x\|^2_H$ for $c>0$

and that $A$ is also compact. But that would be a contradiction, no? Because $A$ injective by the positiveness.

Comment: @AnneBauval yes thank you. But why can this even exists. Is it not a contradiction actually? As any compact operator on an infinit dimensional space cant be positive, as then it would be injective?

Comment: I believe the OP in the linked post is taking "strictly positive" to mean positive definite. No such $c$ exists for the operator in that post and no such constant can exist in general for a compact operator since the spectral theorem says the singular values can only accumulate at zero.

Comment: The condition implies $\|Ax\|\ge c\|x\|.$ Thus $A$ is injective and its range $H_0$ is closed. The operator $B:H_0\to H$ given by $B(Ax)=x$ is well defined and $\|B\|\le c^{-1}.$ Moreover $BA=I_H.$  If $A$ is compact so is $I_H.$ The latter may occur iff $H$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: But even then if $x\neq 0$, and $x\in ker(A)$, we have $0=\langle Ax,x\rangle>0$, so $A$ must be injective. But that means $A^{-1}A = I_H$ for a left inverse $A^{-1}$, thus $I$ compact. Which is wrong when $H$ is infinit dimensional. What do I miss?

Comment: If you're given an explicit construction then it exists. That means your proof of the non-existence is false. You'll want to review the definitions and theorems you've used to see where the mistake it.

Comment: @Furkan A compact operator can be injective. It’s just that, if the space in question is infinite-dimensional, its left inverse is never bounded, whereas the condition you’re asking about implies the existence of a left-inverse that is bounded.

Comment: @DavidGao thats right, thank you!